# IMAP Email Sending Failure

Tags: email, samsung-galaxy-s7, imap, hotmail

In Email, I have 3 accounts, 2 x hotmail and 1 x IMAP. Since the last update (4.1.83.3) where it demanded I give Email access to the Phone, I have not been able to send any emails from the IMAP account. The Hotmail Accounts are both fine. Samsung S7. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have a couple of questions reading this: What app are you using for email? I'm not familiar with one called "Email" in stock Android. Did all three accounts work fine before the update? What happens when you try to send from your IMAP acct? Is receiving also broken or just sending?   I recommend editing your question (rather than just replying to my comments) so that others can better help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Mail - Settings - Accounts and re-input all of the settings, one may be corrupt even though it looks fine.